# onbeforeunload trigger popup only when onload not finished

Tags: php, javascript, onload, onbeforeunload

I am trying to find out if user leaves before pageload is complete but i`m having a little trouble with the after page load is finished cause i dunno how to disable it.
This is part of a search loading page so when page load is finished the user is redirected to the result page but with this script the user is asked if he wants to leave the page or not after search is finished.
The code is bellow and works for both when pageload is not finished as well as when it finished.
Any ideas on how to only trigger this event before pageload finishes or is there any other way to accomplish this?

Thank you.

```
<?php

$var = <<<EOF

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Title</title>
    <script language="JavaScript">
      window.onbeforeunload = confirmExit;
      function confirmExit()
      {
        return "message?";
      }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
asdf
</body>
</html>

EOF;

    print $var;
    flush();
    ob_flush();    
$i = 0;
while($i < 10){
    print $i.'<br />';
    flush();
    ob_flush();    
    sleep(1);
    $i++;
}

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
window.onload = function(){
  // Called once the page is fully loaded to make onbeforeunload a no-op 
  window.onbeforeunload = null;
}
```

Make sure this is the first function in the document so it gets bound first.